# Reverse string in JavaScript using Reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reverse a string in JavaScript using Reduce method. But I am getting an error. Can anyone suggest me how to solve an error?

code ::

```
var reverseString = function(s) {
   return s.split("").reduce((rev, char) => char + rev, '');
};

reverseString(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']);
```

output ::

[image]

Comment: You're passing it an array. `.split()` is for strings not arrays. I think you wanted `.join()`

Comment: Pass the string in as 'hello' not as an array.

Comment: Please post actual code not images of code. Nobody can copy it to test or modify for answers.  [mcve] Also provide expected results

Comment: I don't think `.reduce()` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Indeed, it appears there [is already a function which will do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I usually avoid that function because it mutates an input array. It isn't clear whether the OP wants their input to be an array of characters or a string, but if the former, using `.reverse` is dangerous.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin so `[... s].reverse()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it, just needed to remove the `String.prototype.split()` method, because `String.split()` doesn't work on arrays. Example:

```js
var reverseString = function(s) {
  return s.reduce((rev, char) => char+rev, "").split("");
}
console.log(reverseString(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']));
```

Comment: As an input I want  to use [ ] not just string

Comment: @Riya Check it now.

Comment: The output should be in array only ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']

Comment: Note:  Reversing strings in Javascript is not that easy. This will fail when using combined characters because it reverses the combination of characters too.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you really want to reverse a **string** or an **array**.
Try this if it's a **string**

```js
var reverseString = function(s) {
 return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverseString('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split('').reduce((rev, char) => char + rev, "");
}
```

or

```
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('')
}
```